# Proving existence of a root in second derivative

Tags: calculus

Let $f:[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R} $ be double differentiable function such that line segment between points $(0,f(0))$ and  $(1,f(1))$ pierces function at point $(a,f(a)) $  where $0<a<1$.

So now i have to prove that there exists such $x_0$ that  $f''(x_0)=0$

So i know that the function has a second derivative, but what can i say about it, since i only have the function, not second derivative.

My first idea to somehow to use that line for describing first derivative. And i know that if i do that i will just have to show that f'(0)=f'(1) and will use Rolle's theorem  to prove the statement.
Any help or tips are welcome.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The image of your function $f$ seems off? All points are mapped to $2$?

Comment: @Marc typo, sorry

Comment: @Marc fixed now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us find the line to which $(0,f(0))$ and $(1,f(1))$ belong. It should be of the form:
$$y=\lambda x+\beta$$
So, since it crosses $(0,f(0))$, we obtain that $\beta=f(0)$. Since it crosses $(1,f(1))$, we obtain that: $\lambda=f(1)-f(0)$. So, the wanted equation is:
$$y=(f(1)-f(0))x+f(0)$$
Now, since we know from our hypothesis that $f$ intersects this line to $(a,f(a))$, we have that:
$$f(a)=(f(1)-f(0))a+f(0)$$
From Man Value Theorem (MVT) over the interval $[0,a]$, we get that there exists a $\xi_1\in(0,a)$ such that:
$$f'(\xi_1)=\frac{f(a)-f(0)}{a-0}=\frac{(f(1)-f(0))a}{a}=f(1)-f(0)$$
Now, from MVT over the interval $[a,1]$, we get that there exists a $\xi_2\in(a,1)$ such that:
$$\begin{align*}f'(\xi_2)&=\frac{f(1)-f(a)}{1-a}=\frac{(f(1)-f(0))a+f(0)-f(1)}{1-a}=\frac{(f(1)-f(0))(1-a)}{1-a}\\&=f(1)-f(0)\end{align*}$$.
So, $f'(\xi_1)=f'(\xi_2)$ and, from Rolle's theorem over the interval $[\xi_1,\xi_2]$, we have that there exists a $x_0\in(\xi_1,\xi_2)$ such that:
$$f''(x_0)=0$$.

**Most Importnat part!** All this is almost obvious if one tries to make a sketch of $f$. Draw, at first, the line that crosses it two given points an then imagine $f$ as a smooth curve - no edges - that connects these two points and also intersects ths line to another point, between them. Intuitively, in every case you may imagine - whether it is tangent to $(a,f(a))$ or not - it is obvious that this function will have to turn at least once from convex to concave or vice-versa, so it has an inflection point, so its second derivative has at least one root.

Answer (score 1):

By the mean value theorem, there exists $x_1\in(0,a)$ and $x_2\in (a,1)$ such that
$$f'(x_1)=\frac{f(a)-f(0)}{a-0}=\frac{f(1)-f(a)}{1-a}=f'(x_2),$$
where the middle equality comes from the line segment condition provided. Can you finish it off?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I've misunderstood your assumptions, but I believe there need not be such an $x_0$.  For instance, consider the function $f(x) = x(3-2x)$.  Then the line segment connecting $(0,f(1))$ to $(1,f(1))$ would lie on the line $y=1$, and this segment intersects the graph of $f(x)$ only for $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $x=1$.  Yet $f''(x) \neq 0$ for any $x$.

Comment: Another typo, my mistake, it's $(0,f(0))$ the first point

Comment: I edited it. Check now